# Create TPU instance using Terraform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

I try to create a TPU instance of Google provider using [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) but can't find any proper docs about it on the official site.
It seems that Terraform still considers TPU as a *beta*.

Anybody else facing this issue?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that [TPU is now supported](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/tpu_node.html) in the Google Cloud provider for Terraform (looks like it may be in beta state currently)